# Scalable applications with picocli. Best practice question

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

Say my project does a lot of logic, and has a few entry points, them being CLI commands.

I annotate my entry points with `@Command`, initialize my `@Parameters` and `@Option` annotated fields and perform logic, that doesn't require the CLI anymore.

As I see it, it would suit me to declare 1 `main` method per `@Command` annotated class, however, I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Maybe some kind of `CommandFactory` is necessary?

I've never built CLI applications before or used picocli, so if my thought process is erroneous please point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to have a separate `main` method for each `@Command` that is an entry point. The `main` method is needed so the command can be invoked standalone from the command line.

For example:

```
@Command(name = "hello")
class Hello implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandLine.run(new Hello(), args);
    }
    public void run() { System.out.println("hello"); }
}

@Command(name = "bye")
class Bye implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandLine.run(new Bye(), args);
    }
    public void run() { System.out.println("bye"); }
}
```

One exception is when your application has commands with [subcommands](https://picocli.info/#_subcommands). In that case you would only need to have `main` methods for the top-level commands, not for the subcommands.

Example with subcommands:

```
@Command(name = "git", subcommands = {Commit.class, Status.class})
class Git implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // top-level command needs main
        CommandLine.run(new Git(), args);
    }
    public void run() { System.out.println("Specify a subcommand"); }
}

@Command(name = "commit")
class Commit implements Runnable {
    @Option(names = "-m") String message;
    @Parameters File[] files;

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("Committing %s with message '%s'%n",
                Arrays.toString(files), message);
    }
}

@Command(name = "status")
class Status implements Runnable {
    public void run() { System.out.println("All ok."); }
}
```

Note that only the top-level command needs a `main` method when there are subcommands. 
Even with subcommands, no factory is needed.

Comment: I wonder how good does it scale though. Say I wanted to assemble it into a `.jar` file.
How would I do it if I wanted it to have two entry points, for `myprogram mycommand -o=option` and `myprogram anothercommand -o=option`, so that it would know to launch the separate main methods?

Would I have do play with the manifest to achieve that?

Comment: In your example, `myprogram` is the top-level command, and `mycommand` and `anothercommand` are subcommands, no?

Comment: I'd have to research the subcommands as a thing. If git was made with picocli, would `pull` and `commit` etc. be subcommands? If so, then that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Reading the examples, I've found that subcommands concept is exactly what I need. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Glad to hear that!